# Fatal Error creating Array

Tags: ios, swift

This is the code I have. Basically when the user first chooses the quality of the dinning whether it is fine (20%), casual (15%), or a bar (11%). From there the user will then be asked on a 1-5 scale about the food quality, service, etc. Depending what number they choose, for example if the fine dinning was a 5/5 then it will ad 4% to the already 20 percent (each number will have a selected value to add to the tip). Can anyone figure out what's going on? Or if there is a better way about doing it.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable

class ViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet weak var billTotal: UITextField!

    var diningValue: Double = 0.0
    @IBAction func toggleFineDining(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.highlighted = sender.selected
        if sender.selected == true{
            diningValue = 0.20
        }
    }
    @IBAction func toggleCasualDining(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.highlighted = sender.selected
        if sender.selected == true{
            diningValue = 0.15
        }
    }
    @IBAction func toggleBartender(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.highlighted = sender.selected
        if sender.selected == true{
            diningValue = 0.11
        }
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var service: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var friendliness: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var foodQuality: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var atmosphere: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var overall: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var recommend: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var total: UILabel!



    func totalBill(inputArray: [Double], value: Double, recommend: Bool)->Double{

        var array: [Double] = []

        let total = inputArray[0]

        for var i = 1; i < inputArray.count; ++i {

            array.append(inputArray[i] * 0.01)

        }

        let sum = array.reduce(0, combine: +)

        var totalTip = Double()

        if recommend == true{

            totalTip = sum + value

        } else {
            if sum < 0.15 {
                totalTip = 0.15
            } else {
                totalTip = sum + value
            }
        }

        let tipValue = totalTip * total

        return total + tipValue

    }



    @IBAction func calcTotal(sender: AnyObject) {
        var valueList = [String(service.text), String(friendliness.text), String(foodQuality.text), String(atmosphere.text), String(overall.text)]

        let list = doubleArray(valueList)



        print(list)

        let initialTotal = Double(billTotal.text!)

        let total_bill = totalBill(list, value: diningValue, recommend: recommend.selected)

        print("Total: ", total_bill)

        print(String(format: "%.3f", Double(total_bill)))

        total.text = "$" + String(format: "%.2f", Double(total_bill))

        //diningValue = diningValue




    }




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}

func doubleArray(list: [String])->[Double]{

    var doubledList: [Double] = []

    for element in 0...list.count{

        let doubledElement = Double(list[element])

        doubledList.append(doubledElement!)

    }

    return doubledList

}
```

Comment: The error is right between the two brackets right above the line:                           func doubleArray(list: [String])->[Double]{

Comment: error log or anything?

Comment: does fatal error = compile error or runtime error, more details on what the problem is and what you've tried to do to remedy/diagnose it, please.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in the last function:

```
func doubleArray(list: [String])->[Double]{

    var doubledList: [Double] = []

    for element in 0...list.count{

        let doubledElement = Double(list[element])

        doubledList.append(doubledElement!)

    }

    return doubledList

}
```

Your loop is looping from `0` to `list.count` and it crashes at `list[element]` when `element` is `list.count` (`Out of Index`)

You need to change from `0...list.count` to `0..<list.count`:

```
func doubleArray(list: [String])->[Double]{

    var doubledList: [Double] = []

    for element in 0..<list.count{

        let doubledElement = Double(list[element])

        doubledList.append(doubledElement!)

    }

    return doubledList

}
```

I would recommend you to do it in swifty way:

```
func doubleArray(list: [String])->[Double]{

    var doubledList: [Double] = []

    for element in list {
        doubledList.append(Double(element) ?? 0.0)
    }

    return doubledList

}
```

A shorter version using `map` function:

```
func doubleArray(list: [String])->[Double]{
    return list.map( { Double($0) ?? 0.0 })
}
```